# Decoding string with escaped characters

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

I have a file with lines of Python outputs (provided by someone else) in format literally like this

```
b'z\xc3\xa1blesk'
b'Nicky'
b'p\xc3\xa1ny'
```

How do I convert those to "normal characters?"
I suppose that those are utf8 escapes in Python, and the fist word should be transliterated as *záblesk*.
The words should be in Czech language if that happens to be relevant.

Comment: If you're sure there is no malicious code for hijacking your machine hidden in those lines, you can do: `for line in f: s = eval(line).decode('utf8')`. For each line, `s` will have the value `'záblesk'` etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Those were just short lines of text, so I think the risk is reasonably low.